# MS Access data lineage documentation

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am looking for a scripted/automated way (presumably VBA?) to take an Access query and generate some kind of savable, searchable, publish-able documentation on the data lineage. So if there were a bunch of layered/nested queries, or even passthrough queries, along the way I want a way to trace the final *fields* in the specified query back until I get back to the original source tables/fields.

Everything I've found seems to do database documentation focused on how the table relationships are configured.  I'm looking for a way to get the documentation of the user-created portion, down to the field. I'm very open-minded on what format the output is in. I'm convinced this must be possible, but haven't had any luck yet.

I'm also open to recommendations for a third-party application if it could do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might help if you could post an example of the type of query you'd want this tool to be able to handle

Comment: I think that trying to track through a specific field's history will be very difficult to handle programatically. Not only do you have the issues of nested queries that have to be tracked, but within each query there are lots of things you can do to change a field - including, but certainly not limited to, renaming it , changing the value with a formula, using or changing it inside an iif statement, ....  I don't know how you would figure that all out, other than manual documentation of what goes on in each query.  But good luck - I'l be interested to watch & see if you get any better advice.

Answer (score 1):

Access does have a built in “dependency” feature. The result is a VERY nice tree-view of those dependencies, and you can even launch such objects using that treeview of your application to “navigate” the application so to speak.

The option is found under database tools and is appropriately called Object Dependencies.

The result looks like this:

[image]

While you don't want to use auto correct, this feature will force on track changes. If this is a large application, then on first run a significant delay will occur. After that, the results can be viewed instantly. As noted, not only do you have a hierarchical tree view, but objects in the tree view can be clicked on to launch the object in question.

And the above will work for a query that based on a query etc. all the way down to the base table.

Comment: re: "While you don't want to use auto correct" - I remember there being extensive discussion years ago about ensuring that "AutoCorrect" was turned off, but in current versions of Access there seems to be more than one choice. It sounds like the above procedure would enable "Track name AutoCorrect info" and that would be okay, but "Perform name AutoCorrect" should still be avoided. Is that a fair statement?

Comment: +1 Gord - the track name not usually a problem, but perform autocorrect can be. I suppose some users do benefit from the AutoCorrect, but I tend to avoid the feature.

Comment: Auto correct settings aside, this isn't quite what I had in mind. I've updated my original post to hopefully make it clearer. But thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f73rs3h9u9q2xk5/AAArloN_Cmf_WbPZ4W75I6KVa?dl=0

This is a set of queries I wrote to provide the kind of documentation you're looking for.  It seems a bit kludgy, but it works for me.  It's not a simple as the other response, but it provides output that can be incorporated into other documentation.

Note - the documentation is out of date with respect to Union queries.  The query I have to analyze Union queries seems to only pick up the 1st two things that go into the Union, so I changed this to a Make Table query, and manually edit the resulting table to add the missing relationships.

To use the queries:

1. Copy the table and all the queries into your database
2. Run the "Mapping Unions Make Table" query
3. Manually edit the Unions table if necessary

When you run any of the 3 main output queries, you are prompted for the Top object you want to analyze.  Enter the name of a query or table to find all the dependencies for that object.  The three main outputs are:

1. Mapping Summary - lists all of the objects that go into the top object and all of the objects that go into them, to a depth of about 10 (depth is controlled in the "Mapping all parents" query)
2. Mapping summary without duplicates
3. Mapping summary duplicates

I especially like the 2nd output - this is in a format that can be saved in Excel and input to Visio's Org Chart Wizard to get a simple graphical representation of the relationships.  Then the 3rd output query can be used to manually add in the queries that go into more than one other query, which Visio's wizard cannot handle.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try your queries yet, but does this get down to the *fields* in the documentation? (Updated my post to hopefully better explain my need.) May still be handy for other purposes, regardless.

Comment: no - this gives a map of all the queries & tables, but doesn't deal with individual fields.